# Submit multiple forms (dynamicly created) with one button, each form can be submited individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I'll try to explain the structure of my website and then the problem.

- I have a list of elements, each element has an array.
- I created a form for each element of the array, because each element can be modified individually, and each form has a button save.
- I need to create a button "Save all", that allows to the user fill all the forms and save all elements.

I'm at this point, I tried some other things, but didn't work, like nested forms:

```
button.btn.btn-warning(type='button' name='GCTTested' id='GCTTested' value='UpdateGctStatus' onclick="submitGlbForm('"+formList+"')") Save All
```

- formList is an array with the formIDs of each element

The function submitGlbForm, for each formID I call the submitForm function:

```
function submitGlbForm(array){
    array = array.split(',')
    for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        //console.log("SubmitGlbForm: "+array[i])
        submitForm(array[i])
    };  
}


function submitForm(value){
    //console.log("SubmitForm: "+value)
    var frm = document.getElementById(value);
    //console.log("Form: "+frm)
    //console.log("Form: "+$('#'+value).serialize())
    //console.log("Ajax submit action: "+$('#'+value).attr('action'))
    frm.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:$('#'+value).attr('action'),
            data: $('#'+value).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Save successful');
                //alert(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('Error.');
                //alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is that only one form is submited. Exactly the last one.

Can anyone help me to find why only one form is submited or giving me another approach to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
submit — a button or attribute of button type that tells the browser to take action on the form (typically to send it to a server).

function submitForm(value){
//console.log("SubmitForm: "+value)
var frm = document.getElementById(value);
//console.log("Form: "+frm)
//console.log("Form: "+$('#'+value).serialize())
//console.log("Ajax submit action: "+$('#'+value).attr('action'))
 $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        async:false,
        url:$('#'+value).attr('action'),
        data: $('#'+value).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Save successful');
            //alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Error.');
            //alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

according to me if everything is right then your could should be something like this. there is no need of writing a ajax inside a submit form .

you can directly iterate and send async request. loop is executing faster than ajax so always last reques is firing inside a loop. you can achieve above functionality using deferred promise. visit a [link](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/).

Comment: Ok. Understood, I'll try with deferred promise.
About type of button I know is better use submit, just another thing I tried! Thanks!

Comment: Finally, I don't use deferred. The code provided works fine.