# Form submit is not stop if record found in database

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a time table of lectures where user set record in table row and more than one table row will be added as per required.

I am facing issue that form is submit when any one in table row record is already exists in database.

Is there any way to stop form submit when record is found in database? I am using for loop for checking each row of table.

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" type="button" id="submit_btn">Save<i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>/button>
$('#submit_btn').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault(); 
var a;
var checkalready = 0;
var chkValue = $('[name="chk[]"]:checked').length;
    for(var r=1; r<=chkValue; r++){
        var sessionid = $('#sessionid').val();
        var prev_start_time = $('#class_strt'+r).val();
        var prev_end_time = $('#class_end'+r).val();
        var prev_room = $('#room'+r).val();
        var prev_weekdays = $('#week_days'+r).val();
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "check_multi_timetable.php",
                data: {session: sessionid, startTime: prev_start_time, endTime:prev_end_time, weekday: prev_weekdays, room: prev_room},
                success: function(result) {
                var value = $.trim(result);
                alert(value);
                    if (value == "1"){
                        alert('TimeTable Already Exist');
                        a =r-1;
                        $('#class_strt'+a).val('');
                        $('#class_end'+a).val('');  

                } else{ 
                    checkalready = 1;
              }      
          },      
      });
    }
if(checkalready=='1'){
        alert("Form submit");
        //document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
    }
});
```

User enter a record in 2 table rows then click on save button then javascript and jquery will be check in these 2 table rows are already exists in database or not.

Comment: if you can define a rule for uniqueness you can check it directly on insert on the database. Usually you can define a unique key for this. don't do it on the front end. It is too much resource consuming

Comment: Submitting inside a loop doesnt make sense,probably you should use a variable with value 0 at first & make it 1 in the `else` block ,check if it is 1 after the loop to handle the submit.

Comment: @techie_28 exactly I am doing like this way but its not overwriting a variable

Comment: Could you post that code?

Comment: yes just a minute.. I updated my question check it please

Comment: sorry I did not correctly read your code at first,you are basically doing multiple ajax requests which will give value 1 if record exists else the submit happens,this will surely happen if any of those ajax request gives result anything other than 1,Form submission cant be stopped after that.

Comment: so there is any solution of this problem??

Comment: Ideally there should be 1 ajax request only which takes all the data at once say in an array of objects in the `data:` attribute like `data:[{session: sessionid, startTime: prev_start_time...},{session: sessionid, startTime: prev_start_time2...},]` which can be formed using a loop.The Backend logic should also be changed to loop over this data and return 1 or 0 on found/not found basis.Your current approach is not reliable as different ajax requests are likely to finish at variable time

Comment: Ok I understand your point. thank for supporting

Comment: FYI the variable doesnt get overwritten because ajax is an asynchronous operation which completes in future & `if(checkalready=='1'){` runs before that.This would again be a problem during multiple ajax's.
`

Answer (score 0):

submit — a button or attribute of button type that tells the browser to take action on the form (typically to send it to a server).

if you are using button type submit or form submit it will reload the page.
instead of this

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" type="button" id="submit_btn">Save<i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>/button>
```

use this

```
<input class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" type="button" id="submit_btn" />Save<i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
```

you can check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625561/submit-multiple-forms-dynamicly-created-with-one-button-each-form-can-be-subm/52625674#52625674)

Comment: you dont understand my problem?

Comment: what is your button type?

Comment: change button tag to input type='button'

Comment: this has nothing to do with OP's question

Comment: this will prevent to submit a form

Comment: still form is submitting even record is found in database

Comment: can you check what is returning in "value"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, It will be better to refactor your code at all, because you do too much requests(imagine that user checked many rows, so yuo have 10+ requests or more). Better to optimize your backend and SQL queries. And according to answer from database, send a response to front-end whith value like `{row1Existance: true, row2Existance:false}` and etc.